# How do I introspect all the valid protobuf enum values in Python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Suppose I have a protobuf

```
enum Color {
  RED = 0;
  GREEN = 1;
  BLUE = 2;
};
```

How can I, from Python, get a list of all the defined values and/or names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

enum is like dictionary in python,

You will get keys(names) from `dict.keys()` and values from `dict.values()`.